# How come 'index' is failing to match this rewrite rule?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here are all of my rewrite rules: *(there are no others - this is all of them)*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?action=index
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

When I visit:

```
mysite.com/test
```

The PHP script `index.php` is indeed invoked and has `$_GET['action']` set to `test` as expected.

**However,** when I visit:

```
mysite.com/index
```

...the PHP script reports that `$_GET` is empty. Why does this happen only for `index`?

Comment: Can't replicate the results you note

Comment: @random: Really? Then that **is** weird.

Comment: `/` alone will be empty, but `/index` was sending through to `$_GET` fine

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.2.16 and PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3.

Comment: Oh, and the whole thing is running on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

Comment: I also cannot replicate your results.

Comment: That's bizarre. I have no idea what to do now :) Lemme try another server.

Comment: Wow. I can't even reproduce it on another server running CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* have something to do with your `DirectoryIndex` setting:

http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/mod_rewrite/mod_rewrite-and-directoryindex/